# Nested Form id Getting dropped in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am using vb asp.net and JavaScript,

When I run this code, "payment-form" id, is getting drop. I think you can not have nested forms. But than I need 2nd form inside first one. Any idea how to stop id "payment-form" to get dropped?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
...
 <form action="Checkout.aspx" method="post" id="payment-form">
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="card-element">
                      Credit or debit card
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element">
                      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>

                    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                  </div>
                  <button>Submit Payment</button>
                </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        alert("flag2" + form); 
    </script>


</form>
```

Comment: `<form>` cannot contain another `<form>`, it is invalid. The HTML 5 specification does not describe how browsers should handle nested forms, so behaviour is unpredictable.

Comment: Why do you think you need nested forms? While many ASP.NET WebForms controls do indeed require a `<form runat="server">` often you really don't need those controls. If you wean yourself off WebForms controls then it's much easier to switch to ASP.NET MVC later on because your markup will be generally correct.

Comment: i am using stripe api which also uses form, https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

Comment: You can use your ASP.NET `<form runat="server">` as the parent `<form>` element for Stripe - assuming you want it posting to the same page.